# How do I force intergrated graphics on a Macbook Pro 2011 while using internet recovery?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, gpu

I've got a Macbook Pro 2011 with a failed discrete graphics card. I've been able to install ubuntu on it with some modifications through it's GRUB interface to run on integrated graphics. I followed this guide:

I want to get Mac OS working on this macbook again but I've been told the only way to do that now is through internet recovery during bootup. Unfortunately, when the internet recovery loading bar finishes loading, the screen goes black and doesn't do anything. I think the macbook tries to use the discrete GPU and it fails.

Is there some way to force the mac to use it's integrated GPU like in the link I posted but DURING internet recovery?

Comment: What link did you post?